# Exporting TeeChart (.Net) as PDF

Tags: .net, teechart

I am using TeeChart for .Net, version 4.1.2015.8062; in my forms application developed on .Net 4.0 in VS2010.
I am exporting TeeChart as PDF. When I open the PDF, it does not show complete chart. Only chart title and legends are visible in PDF. Legends have check boxes.
When I export chart without legends, chart gets exported completely.
I have used 'Lucida sans unicode' font for chart title, axis title and for labels.

Does anyone has faced this kind of problem earlier, and have found any workaround for it?

Thank you,

Jaqen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for this. By default, Chart.Legend.Drawlines property was true and was making problem while exporting chart. If this property is set to false before exporting, entire chart gets exported.

Thanks,
Jaqen